# How to get messages from Serial Port in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, broadband

I already have the working codes using USB broadband kit to send a message in VB to mobile phone. Now I am doing the other way which is getting the messages from the Broadband SIM here's the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class ReadSMS

Dim SerialPort As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort()

Private Sub ReadNow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReadNow.Click

    If SerialPort.IsOpen Then
        SerialPort.Close()
    End If

    SerialPort.PortName = "COM4"
    SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
    SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
    SerialPort.DataBits = 8
    SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
    SerialPort.DtrEnable = True
    SerialPort.RtsEnable = True
    SerialPort.NewLine = vbCrLf
    SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000
    SerialPort.Open()

    If SerialPort.IsOpen() Then
        Try
            Debug.Print("START")
            Debug.Print(SerialPort.ReadExisting)
            Debug.Print("END")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("read " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Port not available")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The code above is not working. This line always return an empty value `Debug.Print(SerialPort.ReadExisting)` even if the SIM card has unread messages. Will that be okay if you will suggest me the best thing to do? Thanks Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you can read GSM is to initialize or send command to ask GSM to stream you some messages, the messages cannot stream by itself. I think you are missing the command to initate the stream of message.
You might wana read this http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesReceiveSMS -- these are in C, but the principal remains the same.

Hope this help